# Help with integral / Finding the characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, statistics

I have to find the characteristic function of a random variable that has pdf :

$f(x,\phi)=\frac{1}{\phi}e^{-\frac{x}{\phi}}$, for $x>0,\phi>0$

I know that the charactersitic function for this should be :

$\varphi(t)$=$\int_0^\infty e^{itx}\frac{1}{\phi}e^{-\frac{x}{\phi}}dx= \frac{1}{\phi}\int_0^\infty e^{itx}e^{-\frac{x}{\phi}}dx=\frac{1}{\phi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{x(it-\frac{1}{\phi})}dx=\frac{1}{\phi}\int_{0}^\infty (e^{(it-\frac{1}{\phi})})^x dx $

Now i tried to say that $a= e^{(it-\frac{1}{\phi})}$ so that i get $a^x$ in the integral;

So, i got

$ \frac{1}{\phi}\int_{0}^\infty a^x dx= \frac{1}{\phi} \frac{a^x}{\ln a}|^\infty_0$; Which is clearly a mess?

How do i properly integrate this?

Comment: Hint: what is the antiderivative of $x\mapsto e^{z x}$?

Comment: @Gribouillis Well, if i write $\frac{1}{\phi} \frac{e^{ax}}{a}|_0^\infty $ it takes me nowhere ...The value would be infinite,wouldn't it?

Comment: No it is not infinite. Take $\int_0^A$, then let $A\to +\infty$.

Comment: The way you went is true and there is no mess

Answer (score 0):

Keeping on that way and substituting $a$ from above equation you will have: $\phi(t)={1\over {1-it\phi}}$

Comment: But when i get to $ \frac{1}{\phi }e^{x(it-\frac{1}{\phi})} $$|_0^{\infty}$ doesn't this go to infinity because we have $e^{x*a}$ where is is now $x->\infty $?

Comment: i cant read it :)

Comment: 2 seconds, my latex skills aren't the best

Comment: So as I...don't worry...

Comment: okay, managed to write it correct

Comment: no since -1/phi is the only real part which is negative and makes the exponential to be zero and "it" is imaginary and uninfluential.